# Topology on a product space, such that the projection is not continuous

Tags: general-topology

Can we find topological spaces $(X,T_1)$ and $(Y,T_2)$, and a topology on the product space $T$ : $(X\times Y,T)$ such that the projection $p :X\times Y \rightarrow X$, such that for all $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$ : $p(x,y)=x$, and $p$ is not continuous ?

Comment: Hint: If $U\subseteq X$, then $p^{-1}(U)=U\times Y$. So how do you need to choose your topology on the product s.t. $p$ is not continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial topology $\{X\times Y,\emptyset\}$ has only one non-empty open set. Therefore, unless $T_1$ is trivial as well, that's an example (take the preimage of a non-trivial open set in $T_1$).

Comment: I totally get it, thank you !

Comment: @AliMode You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

No! Its not possible, because the topology product is the minimum topology that the projection are continous.